# Reinstall kitchen faucet supply valve with line to faucet facing downwards?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, valve, hot-water

I Recently installed a new kitchen faucet with a weight on the hose to the retracting nozzle of the faucet ( *black cylinder in picture* ).

Unfortunately, this new weight lays on top of the hot water supply valve ( *hose with red sticker in picture* ) and pinches it.

Is it advisable  to loosen the nut on the copper water supply and rotate the whole valve 180 degrees?

Having the hot water supply line below the weight would, theoretically, give the weight the landing clearance it needs.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If it is a compression valve ( *can not tell from the angle of view in the photo* )  then in theory it is possible to loosen the nut, turn the valve and re-tighten. BUT it is possible that the compression ferule is formed specifically to the orientation and getting a good seal will not be possible. Turn off **main water supply valve** first.

Comment: Alternatively, Place a board at a sharp angle so it covers the valves and the faucet line/weight can slide up and down the free side of the  board.

Comment: yeah, build a ramp or a chute to keep the handpiece flex from tangling in the other plumbing.

Comment: Thanks guys, will attempt the shelf build today and send photos.

Comment: Update: SOLVED! Was able to slightly twist the compression valve and built a slanted shelf to keep the hose from getting tangled in the water supply valves. Will try to upload another photo. THANKS YALL!